# Need to Limit the input timing using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i have two text boxes which takes "from time" and "to time" in the formate "01:00 Am".

My requirement is if i put "01:00 am" in the from time, to time should not exceed 15hrs (means should not be more than "04:00 pm") if the user enters the time which is more than 15hrs in 2nd text box it should show error. please give me suggestions how can i do it in javascript?

Comment: Try something, and then edit the question with a [mcve] of that effort.

Comment: Bro i am not getting how to do that. Just give me the suggestion. no need of full code

Comment: Use the date object?

Comment: No. My input is only time in above format only (ie., 12:00 PM)

Comment: You can't say no to that. If you want to do anything with times (and dates), you will be using JavaScript's date object.

Comment: I Have Developped it by my own without using date/time object. Posted as Answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Developped It By My Own. Working Properly Without Using Date/Time Object.

```
function validateTimeDiff() {

    var startTime = document.getElementById("txt_StartTime").value;
    var endTime = document.getElementById("txt_Endtime").value;

    var startHours = parseInt(startTime.substring(0, 2));
    var endHours = parseInt(endTime.substring(0, 2));

    var startMeridian = startTime.substring(6, 8).toUpperCase();
    var endMeridian = endTime.substring(6, 8).toUpperCase();

    var startMin = parseInt(startTime.substring(3, 5));
    var endMin = parseInt(endTime.substring(3, 5));
    var minsDiff = endMin - startMin;


    if (startHours != 12 && startMeridian == "PM") {
        startHours = startHours + 12;
    }

    if (endHours != 12 && endMeridian == "PM") {
        endHours = endHours + 12;
    }

    if (startHours == 12 && startMeridian == "AM") {
        startHours = 0;
    }

    if (endHours == 12 && endMeridian == "AM") {
        endHours = 0;
    }

    var startCount = 24 - startHours;
    var endCount = 24 - endHours;

    if (startHours == 12 || endHours == 12) {
        if (startHours > endHours) {
            var hourDiff = startHours + endHours;
        }
        else
            var hourDiff = endHours - startHours;
    }

    if (startHours > 12 || endHours > 12) {
        if (startHours > endHours) {
            var hourDiff = startCount + endHours;
        }
        else
            var hourDiff = startCount - endCount;
    }

    if (startHours > 12 || endHours < 12) {
        if (startHours > endHours) {
            var hourDiff = startCount + endHours;
        }
        else
            var hourDiff = startCount - endCount;
    }

    if (hourDiff > 15) {
       alert("End time shouldn't exceed more than 15hrs");

        return false;
    }

    if (hourDiff >= 15 && minsDiff > 0) {
        alert("End time shouldn't exceed more than 15hrs");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```